# Есть ли возможность получить высоту или этажность здания в API Яндекс карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите есть ли возможность получить высоту или этажность здания в API Яндекс карт? Высота отображается на народной карте Яндекс, но как получить ее в API не понятно.

Comment: в векторных тайлах osm(которые рендерит mapboxgl-js) есть эта инфа

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, такой функциональности нет.

Comment: Подскажите, а это планируется реализовать в ближайшее время?

Comment: это лучше в техподдержке Яндекса узнавать. Я о таких планах не слышал.